# Automatic Pasting of content into CKEditor when exiting a model window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor

Is it possible to implement automatic Pasting of content into CKEditor when exiting a modal popup window when the app running in that window is not a CKEditor Plugin?    Would the app need to be implemented as a plug in or can this be accomplished via the CKEditor API?

I have a graphing tool that is launched as a modal popup that is not launched from within CKDEditor.  But I would like to have it automatically place a graph image when into the CKEditor editing window when closing the app.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: If you are using so dialog like jQuery, take out data from it before closing (https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-beforeClose), get editor instance e.g. from variable created during editor creation or simply from `CKEditor instances.yourEditorInstanceNameHere` and insert data using https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setData or https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml or https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertText.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  But a couple of clarifications now that I understand the issue a bit better.   The image being saved from the jquery modal window is stored in a variable in Base64 format.  Can I progamically insert this data into the CKEditor editor window?

Comment: You can use CKEditor API and same code as it has been used in image dialog (create `img` element, set its attributes and insert it):
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js#L400
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js#L405
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js#L439